# Filtering grid rows using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am relatively new to Entity Framework. I have learned how to manipulate data in EF and basics about databinding in gridviews and dropdowns using C#. But I simply can't filter records (rows) from table in database and bind them to grid. Below are few approaches I tried:

To bind full table(this worked b-e-a-utifully)

```
em_dbEntities1 db = new em_dbEntities1();   //"em_dbEntities1" is the Database 
gv_testef.DataSource = db.contacts ;        //"contact" is the table
gv_testef.DataBind();                       //"gv_testef" is the gridview
```

TO EXTRACT A SINGLE ROW BASED ON CONDITION AND BIND THAT TO GRIDVIEW (THIS FAILED miserably)

```
em_dbEntities1 db = new em_dbEntities1();
contact con = db.contacts.SingleOrDefault(p => p.id == 2);

gv_testef.DataSource = con ;
gv_testef.DataBind();
```

Second approach:

```
gv_testef.DataSource = db.contacts.SingleOrDefault(p => p.id == 2);
```

Again this failed.

Kindly help in this regard.

Comment: was there an exception in your 2. approch?

Comment: yeah smthing about"data source can only be inumerable,idatasource ,..smthing"

Comment: ok - you should always post the exception if there is any :) it helps us to locate your problem -

Comment: will do now onwards..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind your grid to a collection of items - the `.SingleOrDefault` returns a single element, while `db.contacts` is a collection.

To do the filtering, you should try using `.Where`.

```
em_dbEntities1 db = new em_dbEntities1();
gv_testef.DataSource = db.contacts.Where(p => p.id == 2);
gv_testef.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thx alot dude...one more thing can u suggest me some good book or online material to read about Entity Framework